# Using cancellation token properly in c#

Tags: c#

I was recently exposed to C# language and was working on getting data out of cassandra so I was working with below code which gets data from Cassandra and it works fine.

Only problem I have is in my `ProcessCassQuery` method - I am passing `CancellationToken.None` to my `requestExecuter` Function which might not be the right thing to do. What should be the right way to handle that case and what should I do to handle it correctly?

```
/**
 *
 * Below method does multiple async calls on each table for their corresponding id's by limiting it down using Semaphore.
 *
 */
private async Task<List<T>> ProcessCassQueries<T>(IList<int> ids, Func<CancellationToken, int, Task<T>> mapperFunc, string msg) where T : class
{
    var tasks = ids.Select(async id => 
    {
        await semaphore.WaitAsync();
        try
        {
            ProcessCassQuery(ct => mapperFunc(ct, id), msg);
        }
        finally
        {
            semaphore.Release();
        }
    });

  return (await Task.WhenAll(tasks)).Where(e => e != null).ToList();
}

// this might not be good idea to do it. how can I improve below method?
private Task<T> ProcessCassQuery<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> requestExecuter, string msg) where T : class
{
    return requestExecuter(CancellationToken.None);
}
```

Comment: What is going to cause your code to cancel? User interaction? You need to create a `CancellationTokenSource`, and then pass a reference to your `Func<T>`  -- you need to check to see if the `Cancel()` method was invoked.  I'll write up a quick sample.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As said in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtoken?view=netcore-3.1), the cancellation token allows propagating a cancellation signal. This can be useful for example, to cancel long-running operations that for some reason do not make sense anymore or that are simply taking too long.

The `CancelationTokenSource` will allow you to get a custom token that you can pass to the `requestExecutor`. It will also provide the means for cancelling a running `Task`.

```cs
private CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

// ...

private Task<T> ProcessCassQuery<T>(Func<CancellationToken, Task<T>> requestExecuter, string msg) where T : class
{
    return requestExecuter(cts.Token);
}
```

**Example**

Let's take a look at a different minimal/dummy example so we can look at the inside of it.

Consider the following method, `GetSomethingAsync` that will yield return an incrementing integer every second.

The call to `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested` will make sure a `TaskCanceledException` is thrown if this process is cancelled by an outside action. Other approaches can be taken, for example, check if `token.IsCancellationRequested` is true and do something about it.

```cs
private static async IAsyncEnumerable<int> GetSomethingAsync(CancellationToken token)
{
    Console.WriteLine("starting to get something");

    token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        await Task.Delay(1000, token);
        yield return i;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("finished getting something");
}
```

Now let's build the main method to call the above method.

```cs
public static async Task Main()
{    
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

    // cancel it after 3 seconds, just for demo purposes
    cts.CancelAfter(3000);
    // or: Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(_ => { cts.Cancel(); });

    await foreach (var i in GetSomethingAsync(cts.Token))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
}
```

If we run this, we will get an output that should look like:

```
starting to get something
0
1
Unhandled exception. System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled.
```

Of course, this is just a dummy example, the cancellation could be triggered by a user action, or some event that happens, it does not have to be a timer.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks for your explanation. In my case I want to timeout after 1000 ms. How can I do in my example? Can you provide an example for my scenario if possible?

Comment: One option is to change your requestExecutor to use `token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` and then in the `ProcessCassQuery` you should be able to use `cts.CancelAfter(1000);` before calling `requestExecutor`. You may catch the `TaskCanceledException` to handle the cancellation gracefully.

Comment: You may/should prefer to propagate the token to the Cassandra Driver and let it handle the token instead of using `ThrowIfCancellationRequested` yourself. Just don’t recall right now if the driver operations support cancelation tokens.

Comment: dont think driver supports that so need to handle it in my code efficiently.

Comment: I see. It seems there's some discussion regarding this subject [here](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CSHARP-566), including a reasonable explanation why it's not supported. Then I suggest you post a working version into the [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) using the `CancellationToken` and the `CancellationTokenSource` as explained above, even if it's not the most efficient version, it's a better place to be guided in that kind of review.