# Meaning of passing CancellationToken to an API Controller's method

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a codebase that has been just developed and all the methods of the controllers have as last parameter `CancellationToken ct = default`

for example

```
public async Task<ActionResult<List<City>>> GetCitiesAsync(CancellationToken ct = default)
```

Is this correct? why they did so? the only reason I can think is of having this method called by some unit test I don't find in the Tests project... otherwise it's totally unnecessary

The developer who wrote this code is not working here anymore so I can't ask

#UPDATE #1
Here's the reason https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62185377/using-cancellation-token-properly-in-c-sharp

Comment: I know how cancellation token works, but I was asking why inside an API endpoint

Comment: I can just speculate. Maybe bad design together with lack of knowledge or understanding. Maybe severeal DEV's with different knowledge have worked an that. Maybe they're using this endpoint controller like a normal class somewhere and therefore have the need for a CancelationToken?

Comment: Look at my update. just found the reason

Comment: Learned something agin. :) But propably a bad design when it's intented to be a long running process.

Comment: We usually don't need it. Most operations don't take so long that we care about cancelling them. But it's a good option to have so that if something does take a long time there's a way to cancel it if it's no longer needed.